# iOS : Create a simple audio waveform animation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, avaudiorecorder

I am trying to record audio with `AVAudioRecorder`. I need to create a simple waveform like this :

[image]

When the user speaks into the microphone a circle indicates the level of the user's voice. I tried to measure the voice with this code but the code did not detect any buffer and not work :

```
func levelTimerCallback(timer:Timer) {

    //we have to update meters before we can get the metering values
    audioRecorder.updateMeters()

    //print to the console if we are beyond a threshold value. Here I've used -7
    if audioRecorder.averagePower(forChannel: 1) > -7 {

        print(" level I'm hearin' you in dat mic ")
        print(audioRecorder.averagePower(forChannel: 0))
    }
}
```

Recording audio :

```
func startRecording() {

        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {

       // Audio Settings
            settings = [
                AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
                AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
                AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
            ]


            audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: self.directoryURL(), settings: settings)
            audioRecorder.delegate = self
            audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
            audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true


        } catch {

            finishRecording(success: false)
        }

        do {

            try audioSession.setActive(true)
            audioRecorder.record()

            TIMERRRRR = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.02, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.levelTimerCallback), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        } catch {

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems that I can see.

The first is that you are testing with the wrong channel number in your function `levelTimerCallback`. Your test should be for channel 0.

The other is that the value of `-7` is actually very loud. `averagePower` returns floats between -160 and 0. Try testing against -160 to start with and increasing that to reduce the sensitivity.

This changes your test to:

```
if audioRecorder.averagePower(forChannel: 1) > -160 {
    ...
}
```

There is only a single channel for the input and the count starts at 0. You have this right later on in your call to `audioRecorder.averagePower`.

To get a linear scale, you'll need to interpolate. Change the value of `scale` to change the range. `proportion` will be between 0 and `scale`.

```
let lowerLimit: Float = -100.0

func levelTimerCallback(timer:Timer) {

    audioRecorder.updateMeters()

    let power = audioRecorder.averagePower(forChannel: 0)
    if power > lowerLimit {
        // proportion will have a value between 0 and scale
        let scale: Float = 10.0
        let proportion = -scale * (power - lowerLimit) / lowerLimit
    }
}
```

Edit: fixed the proportion calculation

Comment: I've added something to the answer that I think is close to right.

Comment: If your proportion is between 0 and 1, that looks ok to me.

Comment: Thanks but the `proportion` starts with 5 when not speaking  to 1 or 0 when speaking

Comment: I've added more details about the scale to the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139741/discussion-between-gary-makin-and-mc-lover).